# Always using the same ARRAY on different querys

Tags: query-posts

I have a function that returns an array os posts ids.

At the moment, everytime i have a query i have to to this:

$ids = agendados();
query_posts(array('post__not_in' => $ids );

Is there a way to maintain the array by calling that on header.php and use this array everytime a do a query_posts?

I think that doing on my way its a overload of querys..

Thanks m8s
Sorry about my poor english

[www.zarpa.eu](http://zarpa.eu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like using categories for this, as they are supposed to be semantic terms. I do, however, like the idea of the global array. Instead of creating a new query directly, I will filter it through a function that will add the results to a global array and return the results:

I add this to functions.php:

```
function nt_globals($args){
    global $used;

    $defaults = array(
        'post__not_in' => $used,
        );
    $query = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    $queryObject = new WP_Query($query);

    foreach ($queryObject->posts as $item):
        $used[] = $item->ID;
    endforeach;

    return $queryObject;
}
```

Then I call the function whenever I want a query:

```
$queryObject = nt_globals('posts_per_page=1');

while ($queryObject->have_posts()):
    $queryObject->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend a different approach:

Create a special category for this set of posts (for example: 'Not in Loop').  Then, when you call `query_posts()` you can [exclude posts based on that category](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category).

However, if you want to stick with your original functionality ... add a function to `wp_head` that sets your array of IDs and then reference that as a global variable whenever you call `query_posts()`:

```
function ignore_ids() {
    $ignore_ids = agendados();
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ignore_ids');
```

Then use:

```
global $ignore_ids;
query_posts( array('post__not_in' => $ignore_ids) );
```

Comment: Its works like a charm. Very thanks m8 :))))

Answer (score 0):

im doing something wrong

here is the code:

function agendados() {

```
global $wpdb;
$ids = array();
$todaysDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$hoje = strtotime($todaysDate);

$query = "SELECT post_date, ID from $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status='publish'";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query);

if ($posts):
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $data_post = $post->post_date;
        $str = strtotime($data_post);
        if ($str < $hoje) {
            $ids[] = $post->ID;
        }
    }
endif;
return $ids;
```

}
add_action('wp_head', 'agendados');

then:

global $ids;

```
$args = array (
'post__not_in' => $ids,
'showposts' => 30,
'order' => ASC,
);
global $post;
$posts = get_posts($args);
if ($posts) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $data = get_the_date('Y-m-d');
            echo $data;echo '<br/>';
        }       
}
```

the $ids array didn't contain anything :/

Comment: Please split this off into a separate question ...